# Multiple MSI vectors - Linux - pci_alloc_irq_vectors return "one" while the device manages more

Tags: linux-device-driver

I’m currently developing a driver for an FPGA based endpoint of our own.

It uses a 1X PCIe GEN2 interface.

The OS is an Ubuntu 16.04LTS (i.e with a 4.10 kernel).

I make use of MSI kind of interruption.

The PCIe endpoint is MSI capable with a count of 8 possible Message Signaled Interruptions and I need to use each of them (each one is for a dedicated purpose)

In the driver code I make use of following call:

```
irq_qty = pci_alloc_irq_vectors (dev, 1, 8, PCI_IRQ_MSI | PCI_IRQ_MSIX | PCI_IRQ_AFFINITY);
```

When I do test using a CoreI7-4790S base board all works fine, the call returns a value equal to 8.

The problem is that my final target platform is Atom E3950 based one and on such target the call returns a value equal to 1 instead of 8 as expected.
I also tested with Celeron J3160 and N3010 and got same issue (i.e. a return value equal to 1 instead of 8)

Did someone face same issue? Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Try making this into a [mcve], please; i.e., I have no idea what `pci_alloc_irq_vectors` is: Can you reproduce the problem at a lower level without it?

Comment: `pci_alloc_irq_vectors` is a pure Linux provided routine to use to manage interrupt requests over PCIe. It is not one of mine. For more info you can have a look to [MSI-HOWTO.txt from bootlin](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10/source/Documentation/PCI/MSI-HOWTO.txt)

Comment: Citing code: *If nvec is larger than the number supported by the device it will automatically **be capped** to the supported limit*. So, make your FPGA be capable of MSI first. Okay, I see you have tested on different PCI host bridges (SoCs) with different results... I would only recommend to double check that your FPGA indeed follows PCIe requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What finally solved my issue is to enable Intel Virtualization and in particular the VT-d option in the BIOS.